# iPhone Animated App Icon

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, animation, icons

Is it possible to animate the icon of an app?
Like the Clock application does?

I implemented the Berlin Clock as app (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mengenlehreuhr) and I'm wondering if this would be possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is nothing in the public API that allows changing the app icon.

Comment: Perhaps on a jailbroken device, but I can't help with that.